# Count columns of different tables based on different criteria and group by a common column join (SQL)

Tags: sql, zoho

I have two tables in which I want to find the count of specific columns based on certain criteria. (Implementing this on Zoho Analytics)

Basically:

1. table1: count rows where column named calltype has field value as demo
2. table2: count rows where column named customertype has field value as 0
3. Group result in months based on a date column present in both

I've tried using sumcase but it doesn't return the correct values -

```
SELECT
         absmonth(A."Call Date") as Period,
         SUM(CASE WHEN A."Call Type"  = 'Demo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDemos,
         absmonth(B."modified") as Period1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN B."customertype"  = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTrials
FROM  "customer_calls" AS  A, "users" AS  B 
WHERE    B."modified"  = A."Call Date"
GROUP BY Period, Period1
```

However, I have codes for calculating each of the count values from the individual tables which give the results perfectly -

Table1

```
 SELECT
             absmonth("Call Date") as Period,
             Count("Call Type") as Total
    FROM  "customer_calls" 
    WHERE    "Call Type"  = 'Demo'
    GROUP BY  Period
```

Table2 (I could've avoided sumcase here but wanted to check if it gives correct results and it does)

```
SELECT
         absmonth(B."modified") as Period1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN B."customertype"  = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TrialCount
FROM  "users" AS  B 
GROUP BY  Period1
```

Basically as an end result I want to find the ratio of TotalDemos to TotalTrials by Month. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong in the first code?

Comment: Not sure why someone has downvoted. Tried to be as detailed as possible. Let me know if anyone would need any more details. I'm new here.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Also, sample data and desired results can help.

Comment: The `zoho` tag was useful to research the `absmonth()` function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Will keep that in mind. Thanks. As, Sander mentioned, I added the Zoho tag as I was working on Zoho Analytics (edited to mentioned that in the question too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically as an end result I want to find the ratio of TotalDemos to TotalTrials by Month.

Try using `union all` and then sggregate:

```
select period, sum(num_demos), sum(num_trials),
       sum(num_demos) * 1.0 / sum(num_trials)
from ((select absmonth("Call Date") as Period,
              Count(*) as num_demos, 0 as num_trials
       from "customer_calls" 
       where "Call Type"  = 'Demo'
       group by Period 
      ) union all
      (select absmonth(u."modified") as Period,
              0, count(*) as num_trials
       from  "users" u
       where u."customertype"  = 0
       group by Period
      )
     ) dt
group by period;
```

I have used the structure of your queries.  I have never heard of a function called `absmonth()`, for instance.  But this should give you an idea of what to do.

I would caution that you don't just want the month for such a query; you also should take the year into account.

Comment: The `absmonth()` function is documented [here](https://www.zoho.com/analytics/help/table/add-formulas/formula-column-built-functions.html). It appears to return a formatted [month, year] combination.

Comment: Anyhow, will test this out in a while and let you know if it works. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: @Gordon One a side note, why wouldn't using Joins work here? (Any particular reason why you've used Union?)

Comment: @Rakshit . . . `JOIN` would also work, but you need a `FULL JOIN` if a given month can be missing from either demos or trials.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This worked. Thanks for clarifying as well.